how to skip numbering but only for first heading in org-export to html
I'm trying to create a blog. And I want to skip numbering but only for the first heading. Which will be the title of the post.
in org:
* Toplevel
** Head_1
  content 1
** Head_2
  content 2

to be exported to:
Toplevel
1.Head_1
  content 1
2.Head_2
  content 2


You can probably use a filter.

Here is your example with a filter that does what you want:
#+BIND: org-export-filter-headline-functions (my/org-html-filter-headline)

#+OPTIONS: toc:nil ^:{}

* Toplevel
** Head_1
  content 1
** Head_2
  content 2

  
* Code                                                                      :noexport:

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/org-html-filter-headline (data backend info)
    (if (eq backend 'html)
        (replace-regexp-in-string ">\\(1\\.\\).*\\(\n.*\\)*\\'" "" data nil nil 1)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
my/org-html-filter-headline
:end:


You can C-c C-c on the code block to define the function that is used by the #+BIND directive1, or you can add ithe function to your init file and evaluate it in one of the standard ways (e.g. by restarting your Emacs).
The filter eliminates the first instance of 1. in the section number of every headline. For explanations of the regular expression, look at the regexp documentation in the Emacs manual (C-h i g(emacs)RET i regexp RET will get you there). I found the explanation for replacing only the first instance of a match in @phils's answer to this question and I cribbed the any character, including newline trick from EmacsWiki multiline regexp.

[1] The #+BIND directive is not enabled by default: you have to set org-export-allow-bind-keywords to t to enable it. See Export Settings.
